# How can I load a xml string or bytes object into a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: xml, pyspark

I understand you can use the sparkSession command `read.format(...).option(...).load("file path")` to load a dataframe from a xml file.

However, within this code I won't have access to any filepaths of the xml just the xml itself as a `string or a bytes` type object.
How can I load this into a dataframe?

I've tried to use `spark.sparkContext.parrallelize([xml_string])` and then submit that into the `sparkSession` read function, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: *it hasn't worked* is not a helpful good description of the problem. Please [edit] your post to relay errors or explain undesired results.